# VTCompressionSession skips first frames

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm encoding with a VTCompressionSession in Swift 3 with the following code:

```
let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
let statusCode = VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(compressionSession!, pixelBuffer!, CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer), CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer)/* CMTimeMake(counter, 1000), kCMTimeInvalid*/, nil, nil, nil)
if statusCode != noErr {
NSLog("VT Error!", statusCode)
}
```

The pixelBuffer variable is the output an AVCaptureSession. The callback of this AVCaptureSession then calls the above code.
The problem is, that the code above is called n times, but the callback from the VTCompressionSession is only called n - 10 times, which makes me wonder where the other frames go. Are they just stored in a queue to improve compression or is this problematic?
My final h264 stream is not 100% correct and I'm not sure if this contributes to the problem.

The VTCompressionSession is created with the following code:

```
var error = VTCompressionSessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                           270,
                                           480,
                                           kCMVideoCodecType_H264,
                                           nil,
                                           nil,
                                           nil,
                                           vtCallback,
                                           selfPointer,
                                           &tmpSession);
```

The VT callback is defined as follows:

```
let vtCallback : @convention(c) (UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, OSStatus, VTEncodeInfoFlags, CMSampleBuffer?) -> Swift.Void =
{
    (outputCallbackRefCon, sourceFrameRefCon, status, infoFlags, sampleBuffer) -> Swift.Void in

    NSLog("vtCallback")
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `VTCompressionSessionCompleteFrames()` to flush those final frames? I've never tried this API, but that call is [mentioned here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/videotoolbox/vtcompressionsession?language=objc).

Comment: Very good guess! 
I did indeed not call it first and just later added it, but didn't recheck. This did not resolve my "deeper" problem, as this apparently was not the root of the problem.
As this however solves the question on where the frames go, this is definitely a good answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! It was lucky, I was looking for a "flush" type api & that was the closest thing.